# How to fill colors in cells of a board in c# when i click on them?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a board in c# using wpf xaml. Now I want to fill different colors on the board cells when I click the button b and click on the cell I want to change color of. How can I do this? The only event handler available for GeometryGroup is Changed... and I am not sure how to do though it?

The code I have written is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="36"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                   Background="Green">Artificial Life</TextBlock>

        <StackPanel Background="Gray"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Expander Header="Main Menu"
                      IsExpanded="True">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button>New Simulation</Button>
                    <Button>Quit</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>

            <Expander Header="Settings"
                      IsExpanded="True">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Board Size:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="False" Name="iicombo">
                        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">10x10</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>20x20</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>40x40</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Background="Gray"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Button Width="50">B</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox Background="Green"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                 Height="50">
        </ListBox>

        <Canvas Name="iicanvas">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="0.0007"></Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup x:Name="iigeomet">
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1">
                                    </RectangleGeometry>

                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.1,0" EndPoint ="0.1,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.2,0" EndPoint ="0.2,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.3,0" EndPoint ="0.3,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.4,0" EndPoint ="0.4,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.5,0" EndPoint ="0.5,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.6,0" EndPoint ="0.6,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.7,0" EndPoint ="0.7,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.8,0" EndPoint ="0.8,1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0.9,0" EndPoint ="0.9,1"/>

                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.1" EndPoint ="1,0.1"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.2" EndPoint ="1,0.2"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.3" EndPoint ="1,0.3"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.4" EndPoint ="1,0.4"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.5" EndPoint ="1,0.5"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.6" EndPoint ="1,0.6"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.7" EndPoint ="1,0.7"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.8" EndPoint ="1,0.8"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint ="0,0.9" EndPoint ="1,0.9"/>

                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            iicombo.SelectionChanged += icombo_SelectionChanged;


        }
}
```

I want to fill the cell with color blue when I click on button b and then click on that cell.
Similarly fill the cell with color red when I click on button c for eg and then click on that cell. and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: look into ControlTemplate.Triggers based on properties like `IsSelected`...

Comment: They are not cells, they are lines that separate regions of the UI.  Consider an alternative like a UniformGrid containing Rectangles so that 'cells' have reachable properties.

Comment: @GarryVass I should remove whole canvas? and use UnifromGrid instead?

Comment: Surely if you want to make a 'board' that has interaction components, it would be appropriate to consider one of the Grid family?

Comment: @GarryVass If I want to put no instead of coloring a cell? what should I use instead of a rectangle?

Comment: A toggle button?  A text block?  A label?  The world is your oyster!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51856/discussion-between-faraz-ahmad-and-garry-vass)